# body = 'cmd=' + urllib_parse.quote_plus(unicode(verb).encode('utf-8')) returns "name 'unicode' is not defined"

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.4

When I run the following python code on Python 3.4

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest, time, re
from selenium.selenium import selenium

class google(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://www.google.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_google(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/?gws_rd=ssl")
        sel.type("id=gbqfq", "")
        sel.type("id=gbqfq", "test")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I have the error `name 'unicode' is not defined:`

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_google (__main__.google)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google.py", line 11, in setUp
    self.selenium.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium-2.43.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 201, in start
    result = self.get_string("getNewBrowserSession", start_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium-2.43.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 236, in get_string
    result = self.do_command(verb, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium-2.43.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 215, in do_command
    body = 'cmd=' + urllib_parse.quote_plus(unicode(verb).encode('utf-8'))
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's wrong? Is there a way to workaround it?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as it says, `unicode` is no longer a built-in in 3.x - instead, the `str` type describes a Unicode string.

You should not be getting this message, because it's occurring within the Selenium code. This indicates that you have installed Selenium improperly - you have the 2.x code but are trying to use it from 3.x.

A quick check of the documentation suggests that 3.x is supported by Selenium - but you'll need to uninstall and reinstall it, and make sure you get it right this time.

Comment: Thanks Karl for your response. Python3.4 binding with Selenium 2.43. Selenium 3.0 is pretty new. How do you Selenium3.0 use Unicode string instead of unicode? Is there any doc talks about how to uninstall 2.x and install 3.0?